# Parsing an XML and binding it to a dialog in an Eclipse plugin

Tags: xml, eclipse

I am trying to write an Eclipse plug-in dialog that parses an xml file and displays its fields using a dialog. The dialog should show the values already populated in the xml file which might be something like -

`<customer>`
        `<name>Erwin Schrodinger</name>`
        `<address>Vienna,Austria</address>`
        `<profession>Physicist</profession>`
`</customer>`

Also, I need to allow the user to edit these values and write back the updated values into the xml file.

I am trying to achieve this using java. My current approach is to use DOM/SAX Parser to parse the fields in the xml file and display it on the jface dialog. I do not have much experience in java, and am looking for some advice on this topic. Would this be a nice approach or is there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a generic dialog that can handle any XML document or a dialog for a specific customer record schema?

Comment: Its a specific document. Say this customer schema will always only these three fields. And these fields are all mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than building a solution from scratch, you may want to take a look at frameworks that makes this easier. For instance, Sapphire, provides XML binding and rendering of forms backed by XML.

http://www.eclipse.org/sapphire/
http://www.eclipse.org/sapphire/documentation/latest/introduction/index.html
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=192